# Python: Grab user input without pausing code

Tags: python-3.x

**EDIT:** This works using threads, the issue I was facing was caused by the IDE I was using which completely halted the program when getting user input. This took me about 3 weeks to realize...

This works perfectly when running it in console by typing `python filename.py`
If you try to run this in IDLE the entire code pauses when `input()` is called.

I heard somewhere something about IDLE using pythonw.exe to execute code and console using python.exe and I assume there's some weird difference in the two that makes it work in one but not the other.

```py
import threading
import time
last_input = None
def getUserInput():
    while True:
        if last_input:
            print(f"\nLast input: {last_input}")
        time.sleep(1)
threading1 = threading.Thread(target=getUserInput)
threading1.daemon = True
threading1.start()

while True:
    last_input = input("\nnew input: ")
```

(this is my first question I've made on here so apologies for any mistakes or unclarities in the question)

Comment: why do you expect it to print True? `user_input` = False, and then it's printed infinitely in your while loop. Could you clarify what you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @trish_s I thought calling the `get_user_input` function would change `user_input` but thanks to Dennis Sparrow's answer I now understand that's not how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to get user input without pausing the code.  I would suggest using multithreading rather than multiprocessing, but either can work.

When you start another process, that process has its own memory space.  In particular, in your case, it has its own copy of `user_input`.  So when the child process changes its `user_input`, that has no effect on the parent process's `user_input`.  Because processes have separate memory spaces, if you want to communicate data between processes, you have to use special interprocess communication facilities.  You can learn about them from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).  There are similar, but not the same, facilities for multithreading.

Comment: Thanks for the great info! I toyed around with threading but even with a setup like this, input() still paused the while True loop

´import concurrent.futures
import time
userInput = None

def a(a):
    global user_input
    while True:
        user_input=None
        a = input("input:")
        user_input=a    

def thread(a):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(main,[1])

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:   
    results = executor.map(thread,[1])
    while True:
        print(user_input)´

Comment: Unfortunately, code blocks in comments are not very readable, as you can probably see.  All the line breaks and indentation are lost, at least with the backtick quotes you used.  I would suggest you either add to your question or start a new question, so your code can be read by others.